# Tableau - Passing result of one calculation as a filter to get data from another data source

Tags: tableau-api

I have 2 datasources. One Data Source provides details of employee (ID, Name etc) and their Departments. This is a Database. Another datasource is a manually maintained excel sheet in a sharedrive that has employee ID and a flag that states if the employee is a New Joiner Or Leaver. This dashboard however doesn't have Department information of employees.

I need a create an Dashboard, where the user can select a department and get details of employees that are flagged as Leavers in the excel datasource.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you join your data in Tableau. First put your database table and then join excel to it. Use ID as a join key.

By joining you will have a dataset where flag is one column among others.